# Passbook, PHP, and signing

Tags: php, openssl, code-signing, passbook

Whenever I try to add my pass to passbook it fails due to:

> Manifest signature did not verify succesfully

My code for signing is below:

```
$privKey = "certs/key.pem";
$keyPassword = "PASSWORD";
$wwdr = "certs/wwdr.pem";
$cert = file_get_contents("certs/certificate.pem");
$certData = openssl_x509_read($cert);

openssl_pkcs7_sign($path . "/" . "manifest.json", 
$path . "/" . "signature", 
$certData, 
array("file://" . $privKey, $keyPassword), 
array(), 
PKCS7_BINARY|PKCS7_NOATTR|PKCS7_DETACHED,
"certs/wwdr.pem");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you properly get data using WWDR?

Comment: Am I supposed to get it any differently?

Comment: Checkout this https://github.com/tschoffelen/PHP-PKPass/blob/master/src/PKPass.php

Comment: Yeah i've forged around in his code but haven't seen where mine trails off.

Comment: Try change "PKCS7_BINARY|PKCS7_NOATTR|PKCS7_DETACHED" to "PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED"

Comment: And i can't see signature "convertPEMtoDER". It's base64 decoded. Is your signature base64 encoded properly?

Comment: Ok I changed the first code, and added the second code part. I am still getting the same error though in the iosSimulator...in Safari my error shares something a little different 'PAPassValidator: _signatureIsValid failed to load signature file'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, using the certificate file, not its contents and removing the PKSC7_NOATTR, since as of iOS 6.1.1, the signature should contain a signing date.

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign($path . "/manifest.json",
            $path . "/signature",
            'file://' . $fullPathTo . 'certs/certificate.pem',
            array('file://' . $fullPathTo . $privKey, $keyPassword),
            array(),
            PKCS7_BINARY|PKCS7_DETACHED,
            $fullPathTo . $wwdr);
```

`openssl_pkcs7_sign` creates an email attachement, so you'll also need to extract the signature part, since this is all the .pkpass bundle needs.

```
// Read the signature file
$email = file_get_contents($path . "/signature");

// Extract the signature using a regex
$pattern = "/.*?Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\".*?\"(.*?)-----.*?/sm";
preg_match_all($pattern, $email, $signature);

// Base64 encode the part of result we need
$signature = base64_decode($signature[1][0]);

// Write contents to a new signature file
file_put_contents ($path . "/signature", $signature);
```

If it still doesn't ingest, check your certificate is a valid Pass Type ID certificate, and that your private key is the correct one for your cert.  You may even want to check your PHP logs to verify that the `openssl_pkcs7_sign` command is executing properly.

---

**Update**

When I try to add your .pkpass bundle to Passbook, I get the following error in the device console.

```
<Warning>: Invalid data error reading pass pass.datafarms.peppermints/123456. Manifest JSON didn't parse: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)
```

Your signature file looks fine, the error lies in the part of your code that is calculating the SHA1 hashes and building `manifest.json`

Looking at your .pkpass bundle, your manifest is corrupt in two ways:

1. It contains multiple objects
2. The SHA1 values do not match the file contents

For this .pkpass bundle, your manifest.json should be:

```
{
    "strip.png" : "f95387c0843a51dac73f1b0a3181da9c99ba3dc4",
    "strip@2x.png" : "f325a97fc6bafbe53a5e8feb7b2c509a8ceb6b10",
    "logo@2x.png" : "7b7b025774128b95e50f2bcda55e608412e95a37",
    "icon@2x.png" : "68b61c27657a0018da71c7f73626c8a891da753c",
    "icon.png" : "6b15fa477ece83fdd4f544a2381444272a0e39a0",
    "logo.png" : "7cf1d842afde33c4b14978f330cf98d05c3e57f2",
    "pass.json" : "971417ec80638736cb3392d6d5db53d554f138a4",
}
```

But it is currently:

```
{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}{
    "strip.png" : "156b528933284a0a58fc316897e1b7d202dfe3e8",
    "strip@2x.png" : "99f5dc1a0c5ed300193f87e42d8632f7251a3f26",
    "logo@2x.png" : "f36816f173aa9011186b80b140dfc49395d31051",
    "icon@2x.png" : "c10dd92e6c043c4bcf6214251d6fcb2a760cd9ad",
    "icon.png" : "d181ad4208e06afb63d5e6049a40521b458da19d",
    "logo.png" : "81c27284f77a447375ba39fb2f0005eeaccf28d8",
    "pass.json" : "e5960e9004d5fff241d77415413d609f47d7b2fb",
}
```

Comment: I tried what you told me to do above and it is still giving me the same error, I know my certificate should be valid, and I am getting no errors in the php logs of anything going wrong.

Comment: Could you post a link to a .pkpass bundle created by your script. This should give some clues as to why it is failing.

Comment: See updated answer - the problem is with your `manifest.json` not with your signature.

Comment: I am now getting this error after fixing my manifest, guessing somehow I am zipping wrong?MobileSafari[5936] <Warning>: BOM could not extract archive: Couldn't read PKZip signature
MobileSafari[5936] <Warning>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.

Comment: Can you post a link to another .pkpass?

Comment: Your manifest.json is still screwy.  SHA1 values look OK, but the object is repeated.  Change .pkpass to .zip, unzip and look at your manifest.json and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I didn't see anything different between my manifest created by my program and a manifest created by a program that is 100% functioning

Comment: Can you post your code that creates your manifest? Looks like it may be appending a string to an existing file.

Comment: This code writes the manifest                                           `function writeManifest($data, $path) {

 $fp = fopen($path . "/" . 'manifest.json', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
 fclose($fp);
}`

Comment: Looks OK, but perhaps try changing to `function writeManifest($data, $path) { file_put_contents(json_encode($data), $path . "/" . 'manifest.json'); }` You should only be calling this function once - are you doing anything else with manifest.json because your current output suggests that there is a loop somewhere that is appending the json object multiple times.